# Availability of EPSG CoordSystem API database

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

In OGC services coordinate reference systems are often referenced by their OGC URI, e. g. http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326

Those URIs point to XML documents at https://epsg.org/api/v1/CoordSystem/6422/export?format=gml that include more information, e. g. on the coordinate system used by the CRS.

http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326 has this for example:

```
<gml:ellipsoidalCS xlink:href="https://epsg.org/api/v1/CoordSystem/6422/export?format=gml"/>
```

If we follow that link, we get another XML document with more information, e. g. on the axes of the coordinate system.

Having to do multiple external network requests is a big issue (latency, availability, security, privacy, ...). So I would like to cache it locally.

Is the entirety of GML documents that this API serves available as freely licensed bulk dataset?

Comment: possibly my answer to this Q (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/461300/availability-of-www-opengis-net-crs-database) is better answered here.  It should perhaps be noted that EPSG doesn't just have codes for CRS, rather it codifies all components all of CRS, such as units, transformations, axes, datums, extents, ellipsoids...  The API and the underlying database includes all these things, not just the CRS

Comment: I am not sure, this question is really about the CoordSystem endpoint of the API.

Comment: The API (https://apps.epsg.org/api/swagger/ui/index) serves data from the EPSG database though.