# Availability of www.opengis.net CRS database

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, ogc

In OGC services coordinate reference systems are often referenced by their OGC URI, e. g. http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326

Those URIs point to XML documents that include more information.

Having to do external network requests is a big issue (latency, availability, security, privacy, ...). So I would like to cache it locally.

Is the entirety of GML documents that this API serves available as freely licensed bulk dataset?

Comment: I think that you know Proj so why not to use it? Test with projinfo `projinfo http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326`

Comment: I am trying to follow whatever the WCS 2 standard throws at me as close to the remote service as possible, that includes using the exact documents referenced.

Comment: * and parsing them.

Comment: The EPSG GML and WKT2 documents are generated from the EPSG database. The data model is https://epsg.org/template/IOGP/downloads/data-model/epsg_mysql_v10.html. The proj.db database follows the same data model so it should work fine as a cache. What EPSG database version is included in proj.db can be queried as `select EPSG.VERSION from metadata`. For me it shows v10.088 that is the current version https://epsg.org/whatsnew.html. But you seem to want GML. Proj cannot generate GML with for example projinfo. It can generate WKT 2 that is as official.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a copy of the EPSG database from [EPSG.org](https://epsg.org/home.html)  You'll need to register, but then it's a simple download.

Multiple variants are offered

[image: EPSG database download]

Comment: The question was about the OGC definitions, main directory here https://www.opengis.net/def/crs/.  The subdirectories drill deeper https://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG, https://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0, https://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326 but there are also other authorities than EPSG. I do not know what all should be copied to the local cache. Maybe you can find information about the licenses from https://defs.opengis.net/vocprez/.

Comment: The subtree of /EPSG/ would be enough, the other databases are not important to me. But I am really looking specifically for the XML/GML representations. I see that "iii" says that this is not offered by EPSG at least. Maybe it is offered by OGC.

Comment: Older versions of the database supplied GML, I'm not sure though when it was removed; you can though still access the older versions so you can check

Comment: You may also want to look at: https://sis.apache.org/epsg.html